# Win Server 2008 won't use assigned static ip (uses 169. instead)

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, ip, vmware-esxi

I cloned a vmware machine on vSphere client, which meant I needed to run NewSID or sysprep to change the SID. As newSID isn't available any more, I ran sysprep without checking the generalise option, this didn't solve the problem (inconsistent sid), so I ran it again but chose the generalise option this time. This solved the problem, but for some reason created another - the server won't configure the static IP address that I assigned to it - it uses a 169 address instead. If I choose to have it automatically assigned an IP it picks up the correct address. There isn't anything wrong with my network, the problem will be on this box.

I have quite proficient networking skills, but this problems eludes me. No other servers have this problem, just the cloned one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I carried out the manual TCP/IP stack reset [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357/en-gb?p=1) which seems to have done the job. I've never some across this before, just luck I found it so quickly.

Comment: Recent (2008/Vista/2008R2/7) Windows versions can have a problem with older DHCP servers, there are various settings that can help (covered in MS KB, but don't have the right # to hand). But that doesn't appear to have been your problem.

Comment: I've had to do this often on 2008/Win7 boxes. Not sure why but I've seen some configurations become sticky and this very nicely blows it out and fixes it.

Comment: I just ran into this problem on a win2k8 server enterprise install. 5 other identical installs were fine.  Good ol' Windows...

Answer (score 1):

I've found that two approaches work well with 2008 and ESX:

1. Disable the DHCP service
2. Destroy/remove the vNICs on that VM, reboot, then create new ones.

Something about SysPrep doesn't create a fresh "GUID" for the NIC virtual hardware, which causes a problem.

Answer (score -1):

I had this happen on a 2008 R2 server also.  The server has 3 ethernet adapters.  2 where "disabled" but plugged into the switch and 1 was in use with a static ip address.

I access the server without issue using the static ip and when you did a ping from another computer on the network of the servername it resolved to the correct static ip.  However, when you did a ping from the server itself it came back as 169.#.#.# which is the address it returns on a failed dhcp assignment.

What I ended up doing is unplugging the ethernet cable on the 2 "disabled" ethernet adapters.  It just magically fixed at that point.  Go figure.  Disable doesn't necessarily mean disable.  Then I did a "reboot" to see if it would stay.  It did not.

Ended up putting an entry in c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts to force it to the static ip. Sometimes one just works around and then moves on.

I tried the fixes listed above but none worked.

Comment: How might one unplug the ethernet cable on a VM?